# Run python script with timeout in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am executing the following piece of code in Jupyter Notebook

```
import os
import shlex

files = os.listdir("./data/")

for file in files:
    %run -timeout=5 -i solver.py ./data/$file
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Desktop/GitHub/coursera/discrete-optimization/week2/knapsack/solver.py in <module>
      1 for file in files:
----> 2     get_ipython().run_line_magic('run', '-timeout=5 -i solver.py ./data/$file')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2324                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2325             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2326                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2327             return result
   2328 

<decorator-gen-59> in run(self, parameter_s, runner, file_finder)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py in run(self, parameter_s, runner, file_finder)
    687         if "m" in opts:
    688             modulename = opts["m"][0]
--> 689             modpath = find_mod(modulename)
    690             if modpath is None:
    691                 msg = '%r is not a valid modulename on sys.path'%modulename

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/utils/module_paths.py in find_mod(module_name)
     60     """
     61     loader = importlib.util.find_spec(module_name)
---> 62     module_path = loader.origin
     63     if module_path is None:
     64         return None

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'origin'
```

Clearly, the timeout option is not working.

What is the correct way to set a timeout option for my code? I want to stop execution for a test case if it reaches beyond a specific time, for example, 5 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
import os
import shlex

files = os.listdir("./data/")

for file in files:
    ! timeout 5 python solver.py ./data/$file
```

Comment: I get ```zsh:1: command not found: timeout```. I am using Mac OS Big Sur.

Comment: Okay, I did a ```brew install coreutils``` and it installed ```timeout``` command. Thanks :)